# Обводка внутри кнопки по границам padding в Мозиле. Как убрать?

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность

В мозиле увидел такую штуку! Точечная обводка внутри кнопки по границам padding-а.

При этом `ountline: none`.

Что это может быть и как от этого избавится?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, сделать отдельный reset файл с

```css
ountline: none.
```

если у активного элемента не работает